# 2 by 2 bit orthogonal encoding mult-kronecker expansion matrices?

Tags: frequency-domain

What is the name of the following bit encoding generator matrices?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called Sylvester's construction for a $2^n\times 2^n$ Hadamard matrix. The matrices are sometimes called Walsh matrices or Walsh-Hadamard matrices.